# I try to use TiKZ to draw the following picture, who can help me fix it

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to use TiKZ to draw the following picture, who can help me fix it

```
\documentclass[margin = 2cm,multi = {tikzpicture}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[Triangle-Triangle,very thick] (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0);
\draw[Triangle-Triangle,very thick] (0,-4.5) -- (0,4.5);
\draw[step = .5] (-4.5,-4.5) grid (4.5,4.5);
\draw[smooth,thick] (-3.5,-0.5) ..controls(-2.2,1.7)and(.5,3.3).. (.75,3) ..controls(2,2) .. (0.4,0) ..controls(-.5,-1.4) .. (0,-2) ..controls(.75,-2.5) and (2.7,-2.5) .. (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add some detail as to what needs fixing?

Comment: thank you for your reply! I want to fix the points that are not smooth, @Zarko's answer is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following better?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin = 2cm,multi = {tikzpicture}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[Triangle-Triangle,very thick] (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0);
\draw[Triangle-Triangle,very thick] (0,-4.5) -- (0,4.5);
\draw[step = .5] (-4.5,-4.5) grid (4.5,4.5);

\draw[smooth,thick] (-3.5,-0.5) ..controls +(0.5,1) and +(-2,0.0).. (.75,3) 
                                ..controls +(0.25,0) and +(0,1).. (1.75,2) 
                                ..controls +(0,-1.5) and +(0,1).. (-.5,-1.25) 
                                ..controls +(0,-2) and +(-0.25,-3.5).. (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem, it looks great!

Comment: You are welcome! When you have sšpare time, try to experiment with ˙hobby` package.